# Why does malloc works but calloc doesn't when we try to use it for multiple strings in C programming?

Tags: c, string, pointers, memory-management

In below code I am trying to use double pointer to access multiple strings as well as each character in every string. This below code is working perfectly as expected. But I wonder why it doesn't work when I remove the malloc statements which are used two times and instead use only one single calloc statement as

```
ptr = (char **)calloc(2, sizeof(char)*20);
```

Calloc statement above does same thing which is done by two malloc statements in below program. Calloc function will simply initialize two arrays of each size 20Bytes. But still I don't understand why this doesn't work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

int i=0;
char **ptr=NULL;

ptr =(char **) malloc(2*sizeof(char));
if(ptr==NULL){
    printf("Memory not allocated!\n");
    return -1;
}

for(i=0; i<2;i++){
    ptr[i] = (char *)malloc(20*sizeof(char));
    if(ptr[i]==NULL){
        printf("Memory not allocated!\n");
        return -1;
    }
}

for(i=0; i<2;i++)   
    scanf("%s", ptr[i]);

for(i=0; i<2; i++)  
    printf("%s\n", ptr[i]);

for(i=0; i<4; i++)
    printf("%c\n", ptr[0][i]);

for(i=0; i<4; i++)
    printf("%c\n", ptr[1][i]);

free(ptr[0]);
free(ptr[1]);
free(ptr);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: *Calloc statement above does same thing which is done by two malloc statements in below program* - no it does not. `calloc` is not magic, it is the same as `malloc`, but initializing the memory to all zeros.

Comment: Your first `malloc()` allocates only two bytes -- not enough even for one `char *`.  If the program works as you wanted anyway then that's a factor of luck, not correctness.

Comment: I notice you are using `sizeof(char)` while expecting to assign to a `char **`

Answer (score 2):

> Calloc statement above does same thing which is done by two malloc statements in below program.

No, it will not.  Setting aside the fact that your first `malloc()` does not allocate enough space even for one pointer, much less two, you seem to be confused about the difference between arrays and pointers.

> Calloc function will simply initialize two arrays of each size 20Bytes. But still I don't understand why this doesn't work.

That's indeed a reasonable way to describe the effect of that `calloc()` call (when it succeeds).  A more complete description might be that it allocates and zeroes space for *an array* of two arrays of 20 `char`s.  But that is *not* the same thing you do with your three `malloc()` calls in the example code.

You go wrong when you assign the result of your `calloc()` to a pointer variable of a type that doesn't match.  `char **` is a pointer to a `char *`.  The pointed-to pointer might in some cases be an element of an array of such pointers.  But arrays are not at all the same thing as pointers, and thus arrays of arrays are not the same thing as arrays of pointers.

Quite possibly you want this, instead:

```
char (*ptr)[20] = calloc(2 * sizeof(char) * 20);
```

or, better, this:

```
char (*ptr)[20] = calloc(2 * sizeof(*ptr));
```

In either case, `ptr` is declared as a pointer to an array of 20 `char`, and sufficient space is reserved for the pointed-to array to be the first element of an array of two such.  You can use the resulting pointer in all the ways you demonstrate doing in your question, except that you must `free()` only the one pointer -- there aren't any others.